# Add multi-select ListBox if intersection contains string

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, activex, intersection

I have previously achieved code to insert a multi-select `ListBox` onto my worksheet based on selection.

I would like to add further conditions to add the `ListBox` only if `Column 7` is selected and `Column 2` in the same row has the string `"variable"`.

Pseudo code:

```
If ActiveCell.Column = 7 and if ActiveCell intersection with Column 2 contains the string "variable" then

Add multi-select ListBox below active cell and 

Output selections to ActiveCell.
```

Here is part of the code I am using currently using. It works to add a `ListBox` to every row in a specified column, rather than to a qualifying row in the specified column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then
        CreateColourPopUp Target
    Else
        DeleteAllPopUps Target
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I add the extra conditions mentioned above?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] and be aware of [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @SamuelEverson I know the above question seems brief and not researched, but it has actually taken me 2 weeks to come up with that simplified version of my question and understand what I was really asking, rather than what I just wanted to see happen as a user. I have asked 2 previous questions regarding ListBoxes, including code and images, which have brought me to this one. I can post code I tried previously, however I feel it deviates too much from this new enlightened understanding of what the code should do. I decided to keep it simple and not confuse the question.

Comment: @SamuelEverson have updated the question to contain code I was previously using and explain further. Feedback appreciated

Comment: A [MCVE] doesn't need to be your entire code, just an *as short as possible* version that still encounters the same issue. The aim is to provide us, the community with enough info to answer and resolve your issue. :-)

Comment: @SamuelEverson Thanks. I was worried it wouldn’t make any sense if only in part.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want it to be `if the selected cell is in column 7 And the value of column 2 in the same row as the selected cell is 'variable'` then run your `CreateColourPopUp` Sub? (or to be more specific has the string `'Variable'` somewhere within the cell?)

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Application.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) method *Returns a Range object that represents the rectangular intersection of two or more ranges.*

I wouldn't approach what you want to do using this function.

Instead I would use the *`Target`* parameter of the [`Worksheet_SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event with all my `If...Then` logic.

Something like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'Makes sure no more than 1 cell is selected.
    If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then 'Not sure if this is required or not but remove this If...Then block if it's not needed.
        If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Offset(0, -5).Value = "Variable" Then
            CreateColourPopUp Target
        End If
    Else 
        DeleteAllPopUps Target
End Sub
```

This adds the extra `If...Then` block to check the following conditions are `True` before creating the listbox's;

- `Target.Column = 7` checks the selected cell is in column 7.
- `Target.Offset(0, -5).Value = "Variable"` checks the value of the cell 5 columns to the left of the selected cell is `"Variable"`.

For the syntax of the `Offset` property, see the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset).